# getWhere() must be of the type int or null and 1 more problem CI4

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Please kindly to help me with my CI4.

This is the Model in CI4-> ItemsCatModel.php

```
public function get_items_cat() {
   $builder = $this->table('items_category');
   $query = $this->table('items_category')->orderBy('items_cat_id', 'asc')->getWhere($this->table, array(['items_flag' => 1], ['items_cat_id !=' => 6]));
   return $query->getResultArray();
}

public function get_items_cat_bi($id) {
   $query = $this->query("SELECT * FROM items_category WHERE items_cat_flag = 1 AND items_cat_id <> ' . $id . ' ORDER BY items_cat_id ASC");
   return $query->getResultArray();
    }
```

when I use the get_items_cat this is the Error pointing at **array()**
**Argument 2 passed to CodeIgniter\Database\BaseBuilder::getWhere() must be of the type int or null, array given**

and I've tried this query too.. **question**-> is it the same query with the above query? or is it different?

```
$query = $this->query("SELECT * FROM items_category WHERE items_cat_flag = 1 AND items_cat_id <> 6 ORDER BY items_cat_id ASC");
```

if the answer is the yes its same, the query **above** is running well.

but if i use the query **above**, when i'm running with my controller it failed.

This is the controller -> Home.php

```
public function __construct() {
   $this->bannersModel = new BannersModel();
   $this->itemsModel = new ItemsModel();
   $this->itemsCatModel = new ItemsCatModel();
}

public function index() {
   $data['items'] = $this->itemsModel->get_items();
   $data['items_lain'] = $this->itemsModel->get_items_lain();

   $i = 0;
   foreach ($data['item'] as $key => $value) {
      $category = $this->itemsCatModel->get_items_cat_bi($value['items_cat_id']);
      $data['items'][$i]['category'] = $category;
   }
   $i++;
}
```

and the error was like this
**Cannot use object of type stdClass as array**
and this is the error start
**`$category = $this->itemsCatModel->get_items_cat_bi($value['items_cat_id']);`**

Please kindly to help me to solve the problem.
Thank You in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Explanation:

PART 1:

The [`\CodeIgniter\Model`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/749307e1b57cfe65705d37fea0a1a957b28eb24e/system/Model.php#L73) class all userland models extend has **no** built-in `table(...)` method. Hence, the line of code below in your custom `get_items_cat()` method should have thrown an error.

`$builder = $this->table('items_category');`

I assume, you meant to use `$builder = $this->db->table('items_category');` instead.

PART 2:

> [`$builder->getWhere()`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#builder-getwhere)
>
> - Identical to the `get()` method except that it permits you to add a “where” clause in the first parameter, instead of using the
>   `$builder->where()` method:

---

> [`getWhere`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/749307e1b57cfe65705d37fea0a1a957b28eb24e/system/Database/BaseBuilder.php#L1706)
>
> - Allows the where clause, limit and offset to be added directly.

```bash
public function getWhere(
    $where = null,
    ?int $limit = null,
    ?int $offset = 0,
    bool $reset = true
)
```

Based on the references above, the method being discussed expects a `$limit` which is an `int` or `null`. Yet you fed in an array instead (`array(['items_flag' => 1], ['items_cat_id !=' => 6])`).

##### Solution:

Instead of passing the `WHERE` condition(s) in the second argument, do that in the first argument instead. I.e:

```php
// ...

$query = $this->db
    ->table('items_category')
    ->orderBy('items_cat_id', 'ASC')
    ->getWhere(
        [
            ['items_cat_flag =' => 1],
            ['items_cat_id !=' => 6]
        ]
    );

// ...
```

##### Addendum

It also looks like your `foreach` loop in your `index()` custom method is erroneous.

```php
public function index() {
   $data['items'] = $this->itemsModel->get_items();
   // ...

   $i = 0;
   foreach ($data['item'] as $key => $value) {
      // ...
   }
   $i++;
}
```

I greatly suspect that you meant to have the line of code `$i++;` placed inside the `foreach` loop instead. Otherwise, `$i` will *always* be set to `0`.

Secondly, you tend to be looping through `$data['item']` yet your initial declaration refers to `$data['items']`. Notice the **difference** in the pluralization of the word *'item'*.

Comment: Thank you @steven7mwesigwa for responding for my problems. I've adjusting as you suggested.  but there is an error within the foreach ```foreach ($data['items'] as $key => $value) { **$category = $this->itemsCatModel->get_items_cat_bi($value['items_cat_id']);** $data['items'][$i]['category'] = $category; }``` the error was **Cannot use object of type stdClass as array** can You point me again about this. Thank You in advanced.

Comment: oh by the way, after that error I've tried using json_decode to solve the problem. but not working since it will run another error like this **json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given** the code was like this ```$i = 0; foreach ($data['items'] as $key => $value) { $category = $this->itemsCatModel->get_items_cat_bi($value); $data['items'][$i]['category'] = json_decode($category); $i++;```